# WPF Powershell App Hangs on Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod

Tags: wpf, powershell, powerbi

I have created a Powershell WPF app using XAML and within my app I allow the user to create a Power BI Streaming Dataset within a particular workspace that they authenticate to beforehand using Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount.  The user clicks a button that is connected to an event and immediately Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount is fired, which triggers a Microsoft OAuth login and assuming the user is authenticated everything runs perfectly fine.  However, the step immediately after involves making a Post request with Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod using the parameters passed in from my WPF inputs the user filled out.  At this point, my WPF app freezes and it appears that nothing has happened, but when I check powerbi.com I can clearly see the dataset has been created.

It seems to me that for whatever reason a response code of 201 is not being returned to my WPF app.  I have my powershell window open and can clearly see no response once the post has been made.  Is this a synchronous issue that specifically related to firing a post request inside a WPF app on button click?

Edit: I just realized that when I close my WPF app, I can see the response code in my Powershell console so it is definitely something on the WPF side blocking the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by reviewing other posts on SO of individuals who had similar issues making API requests with their C# WPF Apps.  I am not 100% sure why a response is not returned to the WPF app so it can continue on, but from what I read it has to do with a button event handler being a synchronous call and since a 201 response is never received, it just holds the application frozen until a user closes it down.  I was able to do the powershell equivalent of C# multithreading by invoking a command as a powershell job making the call async. It is still odd to me because the call itself to post the dataset to powerbi is very fast.. I could understand this issue if the response was slow, but it seems like the response never came, which is what I found so odd.

Code:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($body)
    Login-PowerBIServiceAccount #even though this is an async call, start-job fires off a thread locally so we can don't need to store credentials and pass them to the following command as that is done automatically.
    Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'myEndpoint' -Method Post -Body $body -Verbose #-Headers $PBIToken
    } -ArgumentList $body
```